# Unsubscribe token not being sent to email?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make an unsubscribe from email list button, and so far I've gotten the token back, but it isn't in the format that I would like.

For example, I'm getting close but it's in a format that I cannot retrieve from.
[image]

Here is what my code looks like:
**new-post.blade.php**

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => url('/unsubscribe?token=' . $subscription)])
Click here to unsubscribe
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

**NewPostMail.php**

```
class NewPostMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subscription;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subscription)
    {
        $this->subscription = $subscription;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact.new-post');
    }
}
```

**PostController.php**

```
if (isset($request->subscribers)){
    $subscriptions = Subscription::select('email')->get();
    $subscription = Subscription::select('confirmation_token')->get();
    Mail::to($subscriptions)->send(new NewPostMail($subscription));
}
```

**My table structure**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('confirmation_token', 25)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I try to put $subscription->confirmation_token in the mailable, it says that confirmation_token doesn't exist in the instance, so I'm just wondering why it's returning it in this format and not allowing me to use the data from within it.

Can someone let me know what's going on? I have also tried to use $subscription['confirmation_token'] to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `url('/unsubscribe?token=' . $subscription->confirmation_token)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it says confirmation_token does not exist on this instance.